# Trying to import a variable from another JS file in order to use it in a different JS file

Tags: javascript

[variables from 1st JS file I wanna export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKY7G.png)
[once the function is processed the value is assigned to the variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hgml2.png)

[in the second file I try to import them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJgfq.png)
 [but it does not log! and even makes the function of the burger menu to not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zROZ.png)

[Website's first page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wleB.png)
[Website's second page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qp0QM.png)

Hi, this is my first post/question here-1 I'm a newbie, I started learning fronted development around 6 months ago!

In this little project, I'm stuck! What I'm trying to attain, is that in the 1st page the user selects the color, and that once he moves to the 2nd page, the color keeps the same as in the previous page.

In the 1st JS file, I assign to variable (colorPicked & furniturePicked) in which I'mma assign the text route for the image and color code. Then, somehow I'll have to get access to them in my 2nd JS file. Researching, I stumbled accross with JS modules, followed the steps, but not working. (I haven't studied well JS modules, but I'm guessing it works for a single html file). Thus, I'm stuck again! I would appreaciate any help that comes from the any of you!

What I tried is written above

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the `colorPicked` variable is not updating in `app.js` is that you are trying to reassign a value to an imported variable, which is not allowed in ES6 modules. Imported variables are read-only, so you cannot directly reassign a new value to them.

But you can create method to do the jobs.

```
//app.js
let colorPicked = ''

export function getColor(){
  return colorPicked
}

export function setColor(newColor){
  colorPicked = newColor
  return colorPicked
}
```

Now in colorPicked.js you can use these functions to read and write the variables.

```
console.log(getColor()); // This should log 'red'
setColor("green");
console.log(getColor()); // This should log 'green'
```

You need to add these file links to your HTML file.

If you don't want to add `colorPicked.js` file into HTML, then you need to import `colorPicked.js` file into `app.js` file.

```
//app.js
import "./colorPicked";

let colorPicked = "red";

export function getColor() {
  return colorPicked;
}

export function setColor(newColor) {
  colorPicked = newColor;
}
```

and

```
//colorPicked.js

console.log(getColor()); 
// This will log "nothing" because this logs runs
// before colorPicked value has been assigned


setColor("green");
console.log(getColor()); //This will log 'green'
```